# How to insert or update mysql table with 3 keys

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this in my mysql:

```
location(char17), id(int9), sideid(int9), total(int9), other...(other)
```

I have to insert into new things into this table ONLY if ID and SideID are not found, and update if they are both the same. My dilemma is that I need it to check if ID and SideID exist.

So after adding a few things to my table it should look something like this:

```
mplace1, 100, 4, 10, other data...
mplace1, 100, 5, 6,  other data...
mplace1, 100, 3, 6,  other data...
mplace1, 50,  3, 6,  other data...
mplace1, 50,  6, 6,  other data...
```

Those first 3 columns are basically one giant key. there can be multiple locations, multiple ID's within a location, and multiple SideID's within it. BUT it cannot have one that matches completely. So if the Location, ID, and SideID all match, it should not be inserted into the database, but update the "other data".

Its also really important to have this in one single mysql_query... I've tried for weeks now, and am still lost. Hope someone has an idea of how to do this. Note that if it cant be done in one single query, then I'll guess I'll accept that. This is an exceptional task.

Just to clarify. I mean that those 3 columns(location,id,side) together cant be repeated. So the other columns will be able to have different values.

So if **mplace1, 100, 4, 10, "Some other data 1"** was in the table. inserting this **mplace1, 100, 4, 999, "Some other"** would update. How does one specify what columns to check and what doesn't matter.

Comment: Update Set ... [] Where ID = SideID ?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

This will automatically check for duplicates (duplicate ID's as example) so if needed it does `update` else it does just `insert` a new row.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

Comment: `INSERT OR REPLACE` is not valid `mysql` syntax. I believe you are looking for `INSERT IGNORE`